# Get the arraylist stored id from the clickable item on the autocompletextview

Tags: android, arraylist, autocompletetextview

So my problem is this I need to get the respective "id" field stored in my arrylist that correspond to the selected autocompletextview item and I can't do this. I parse data to a json format and store it in arraylist, and what I want is to click on the dropdown list of the autocompletetextview (already working) item, and get the respective id.

Json Data:

```
{"estab":[{"id":"00","design":"NULL"},
{"id":"01","design":"Continente de Viana do Castelo"},
{"id":"02","design":"Pingo Doce Viana do Castelo"},
{"id":"03","design":"Pingo Doce - Portuzelo (Viana Castelo)"},
```

Arraylist get and set:

```
public class Estbs {

 private String id;

private String design;



 public String getID() {
 return id;
 }

public void setID(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

 public String getDesign() {
 return design;
 }

public void setDesign(String design) {
 this.design = design;
 }
```

}

main/json function

```
JSONArray jsonarray;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ArrayList<String> establist;
ArrayList<Estbs> estab;
 String x;



  private AutoCompleteTextView actv;



 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.add_linha);




 //Download JSON file AsyncTask
 new DownloadJSON().execute();

 }

//Download JSON file AsyncTask
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

 @Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
// Locate the WorldPopulation Class 
estab = new ArrayList<Estbs>();
// Create an array to populate the spinner 
establist = new ArrayList<String>();
// JSON file URL address
jsonobject = JSONfunctions
        .getJSONfromURL(url_donload_estbs);

try {
    // Locate the NodeList name
    jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("estab");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
        jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

        Estbs estabs = new Estbs();
        estabs.setID(jsonobject.optString("id"));
        estabs.setDesign(jsonobject.optString("design"));
        estab.add(estabs);

        // Populate spinner with country names
        establist.add(jsonobject.optString("design"));

    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
}

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
// Locate the spinner in activity_main.xml
actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);


// Spinner adapter
actv
        .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Newlin_ProductActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                establist));

// Spinner on item click listener
actv
        .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                    View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Locate the textviews in activity_main.xml
  TextView txtrank = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.design);

                // Set the text followed by the position 
                txtrank.setText("Rank : "
                        + estab.get(position).getID());

                x = estab.get(position).getID();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), x,
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
}
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check bellow code :-

@Override

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
        long arg3) { 

      String selection = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

      int id;

      for (int i = 0; i < establist.size(); i++) {

        if(estab.get(i).getDesign().equals(selection))
             {
               id=estab.get(i).getId();
                break;
              }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In short `onItemClicklistener()` did the job but i would suggest you to have a look at the code below and try following such practise in daily coding.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    private ArrayList<String> establist;
    private ArrayList<Estbs> estab;
    private AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;
    private TextView txtRank;
    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);
        autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        txtRank = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        estab = new ArrayList<Estbs>();
        establist = new ArrayList<String>();
        new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }

    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                fillDataInEstabs();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    establist));
        }
    }

    private void fillDataInEstabs() {
        Estbs e = new Estbs();
        e.setId(String.valueOf(count));
        e.setDesign("Hello " + String.valueOf(count));
        estab.add(e);
        establist.add(e.getDesign());
        count++;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {
          String selection = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
          int actualPosition = estab.indexOf(selection);
          txtRank.setText("Rank : " + estab.get(actualPosition).getId());
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), estab.get(actualPosition).getId(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry but i dont understand what y did to the json data

Comment: oh ok im gona try it then just tell me why this for for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                fillDataInEstabs();
            }
            return null;
        } just goes to i<10

Comment: autoCompleteTextView.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
this line only works like this, and it shuts down

Comment: i only changed my code to onclicklistener and it works more a less lol, it now shows the ids but not the correct ones as y can see in my json data "continente viana do castelo" is id 01 but when i start to write in the actv the list starts to shrink until it only shows one item so when i click on it, it corresponds to the id in that position = 00 that corresponds to "NULL". if i type "Pingo Doce - Portuzelo (Viana Castelo)" it correspondes to = 00 too. how can i fix it

Comment: y have int actualPosition = estab.indexOf(actualPosition); this shouldnt be  estab.indexOf(selection);??? and String selection = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);using my code the parent should be arg0 right?

Comment: @user3734013 Sorry, was a typo. Yes it should be `estab.indexOf(selection)` and as per your code it'll be `arg0`.

Comment: ok thanks no prblem if it works i rate y thanks a lot for trying to help

Comment: @user3734013  If it helped you kindly upvote(+1) and select this as the answer by ticking the right mark.

Comment: it doesnt work, it shuts down and shows this java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=40; index=-1